# How to access a computer from a USB-cable-android-connected device?

Tags: android, deployment, usb, device

I am trying to deploy and test my application on an android device which is then connected to my laptop with a usb-cable. **Now, how can I target a webapp deployed on my laptop ?**
knowing that my **wifi is down** and that I don't have the right to change router configuration to do some IP port forwarding tricks (in case you would like to suggest me to use the mobile network e.g 3G, go on internet and get back in via our router external IP address ==> which is also a little bit heavy given what we want to do here)

According to the android documentation, "the emulator" can use the ip address 10.0.2.2 to access the hosting computer but there is nothing for devices...

thanks in advance guys,

Comment: Actually you have an option. If you have a server on internet, then you can just deploy the app you want to target on it and then change the target IP Address in your android app to that servers' address.